# Comparing first sheet to second sheet name, if name matched in second sheet then insert the row into the first sheet based on name

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks that have different column structures. I want to compare names from the "studentMaster" sheet and "wpl" sheet, if the name matched in "wpl" then copy the row value and insert it into the "studentMaster" sheet.

[image: studentMaster]

[image: wpl]

My code:

```
Sub findWPLMarks()

'Declare the workbook
Dim studMaster As Workbook, WPL_Result As Workbook

'Destination sheets
Dim MstdataSh As Worksheet, wplSh As Worksheet

'Declare the variables
Dim i As Long, j As Long, foundrow As Long, rowInc As Long, colInc As Long
Dim lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long, lastcol As Long
Dim mstFName As String, WPLFName As String
Dim WPLfldName As String, folderPath() As String

'Declare the path value
mstFName = Range("C15").Value
WPLFName = Range("B9").Value

'Split the file name path
folderPath = Split(WPLFName, Application.PathSeparator)

WPLfldName = folderPath(4)

'Set Workbook
Set studMaster = Workbooks.Open(mstFName)
Set WPL_Result = Workbooks.Open(WPLFName)

'Master sheet
Set MstdataSh = studMaster.Sheets("StudentDetails") 'ws2
'Destination sheet
Set wplSh = WPL_Result.Sheets("WPL") 'ws1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastrow1 = MstdataSh.Cells(MstdataSh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = wplSh.Cells(wplSh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastcol = MstdataSh.Cells(6, MstdataSh.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Debug.Print (lastcol)
rowInc = 7

For i = 1 To lastrow1
colInc = 4

On Error Resume Next
foundrow = wplSh.Range("A2:A" & lastrow2).Find(MstdataSh.Cells(i, 4).Value).Row
'foundrow = MstdataSh.Range("D7:D" & lastrow1).Find(wplSh.Cells(i, 1).Value).Row    
If Err.Number = 91 Then
   ' ws3.Cells(i, 1) = ws1.Cells(i, 1)
   'MstdataSh.Cells(i, 1) = wplSh.Cells(i, 1)
   'Debug.Print wplSh.Cells(i, 1)
Else
    For j = 1 To lastrow2
        'ws3.Cells(i, j) = ws2.Cells(foundrow, j)
        MstdataSh.Cells(foundrow, colInc) = wplSh.Cells(foundrow, j)            
        colInc = colInc + 3
    Next j
End If
rowInc = rowInc + 1
Next i

'Close workbook
studMaster.Close savechanges:=True
WPL_Result.Close savechanges:=True
'ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

If the Assessment Date is different for the duplicate students' in the "wpl" sheet then need to select the best value for each column for that student.

Could you help me insert the row into the "studentMaster" sheet?

Comment: What is the problem with your code?  Why are you using `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: My problem is the value isn't inserted into the correct column in the "studentMaster" sheet.

Comment: I got a runtime error msg, so I used On Error Resume Next (object variable or with block not set) -> foundrow = wplSh.Range("A2:A" & lastrow2).Find(MstdataSh.Cells(i, 4).Value).Row

Comment: Your code will also bypass any subsequent errors. I suggest you put option explicit at the top of your macro. Remove the on error resume next. Then figure out why your find method is not finding anything.

Comment: "wpl" sheet has a duplicate record, if remove the on error resume next it shows an error msg. Please advise and help... thanks.